# Android: Set a background color and a translucent background image on the Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android activity which has three buttons. I have set a color for the main activity `LinearLayout`'s background via:

```
android:background="@color/homeBgColor"
```

I want to put up a translucent background image behind the buttons on the activity. I tried using an `ImageView`, but it pushes the buttons down.

Is there any way to set the background color as well as image for the activity, like we do in CSS?

```
#mydiv{ backround: #262626 url("link-to-my-img.png");}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a [`<layer-list />` drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). Within it, place an `<item />` which contains a `<bitmap />` (example stolen from the developer docs):

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Then, your other item can just be a solid color. Make a drawable resource that just has that solid color in it, then combine them:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_color" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

(You may have to flip the order of the `<item />` tags, I forget which is on top.)